# Chrome browser back for multiple Youtube API iframe has load wrongly

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have problem on my application with multiple youtube load in one page. I use youtube API to load the iframe.
However, in chrome found one intermittent bugs. Sometime when go to another page and click browser back, the iframe youtube will loaded wrongly.
Checked the script it was call correct youtube ID for each tag, with inspect element to check the iframe youtube ID and it also correct. But the iframe content is wrong when browser back.

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a logged [**issue 395791**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395791) in Chromium issues tracker, and based from that thread, a workaround to avoid this bug which already worked for some is to give each iframe a name, since the HistoryItems would get matched up correctly.